# MACRO with variable arguments?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros

The following code is in visual studio 2013.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2 = int>
int  TestFucntion(T1 value1, T2 value2 = T2())
{
    return 1;
}

#define LOG_FATAL( format, ...) TestFucntion(format, __VA_ARGS__, 1)

#define LOG_FATA2_INNER(format, ...) TestFucntion(format, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_FATA2(format, ...) LOG_FATA2_INNER(format, __VA_ARGS__, 1)

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    LOG_FATAL(L"abc"); // compile ok
    LOG_FATA2(L"abc"); // error C2059: syntax error : ','
}
```

Is any way to remove the compile error in  LOG_FATA2(L"abc")?

[See it in online compiler](http://rextester.com/DWUTI77847)

Comment: The first call shouldn't compile either. The macro takes two or more arguments and you gave it one.

Comment: What do you want to achieve using this code?

Comment: Terrible question since there's no error given, just "help error".

Comment: @Puppy http://rextester.com/DWUTI77847

Comment: @Puppy Sorry, difficult for me to describe error. would you suggest one? Thank you.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus If you are interested.
#define LOG_WARN_REGULAR(str, ...) \
    LOG_WARN(str ## _T("; File: %s, Line: %d, Function: %s"), __VA_ARGS__, __FILEW__, __LINE__, __FUNCTIONW__)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual C++ extension you're using, where mandatory macro arguments may be omitted and where `, __VA_ARGS__` is expanded to nothing if no macro arguments were passed, is not completely fool-proof. In your example, you've managed to create a program where the preprocessor doesn't realise that `,` should be removed. Anyway, you don't need that extension here. You can easily re-work your code so that it works with any compiler.

```
#define LOG_FATAL(...) TestFunction(__VA_ARGS__, 1)

#define LOG_FATA2_INNER(...) TestFunction(__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_FATA2(...) LOG_FATA2_INNER(__VA_ARGS__, 1)
```

The format string has become just one of the variable arguments, here.